# How to make ListView scrollable?

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.android

I have a `ListView` (below) and I want to make it scrollable. I cannot insert `ScrollView` inside `.axml` file, because it should only contain `TextView` or `CheckBox` (in this case it is CheckBox). Is there any code which would make my list scrollable? Thanks in advance!

```
public class Activity1 : ListActivity
{
    string[] data = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"} ;

       protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
       {
          base.OnCreate (bundle);
          ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter (this, Resource.Layout.CheckBoxItem, data);    
          ListAdapter = adapter;
       }   
       protected override void OnListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)    
       {
          base.OnListItemClick (l, v, position, id);
          Toast.MakeText (this, data [position], ToastLength.Short).Show ();             
       }    
}
```

Comment: `ListView`s scroll on their own. When you have enough items in your dataset to fill it past its bounds, you'll be able to scroll it.

Answer (score 1):

As Mike M. mentioned in a comment, you don't need to implement the scrolling. It's implemented by default in a `ListView`. If there are more items in your `string[] data` than the `ListView` can display, you will be able to scroll through the `ListView`.